# The Speed of Letters

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a string as input, print a new string with each letter pushed to the right by its respective alphabet index.

We all know that A is a slow and Z is a fast letter. This means that Z gets shifted to the right by 25 spaces, A doesn't get shifted at all and B gets shifted by 1 space.

Your program only has to handle uppercase letters from A-Z, and no other characters, no whitespaces, no punctuation.

Note that if 2 or more letters fall onto the same space after shifting, the latest character will be used. (Example: `BA` ->  `A`)

### Examples

```
"AZ" -> "A                         Z"

"ABC" -> "A B C"

"ACE" -> "A  C  E"

"CBA" -> "  A"

"HELLOWORLD" -> "     E H    DLL   OLO   R  W"
```

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in any language bytes wins.
- Standard loopholes are forbidden.
- Input must be received as a string.
- You may print the result to `stdout` or return a string.
- A *single* trailing whitespace and/or newline is allowed.
- You may also use lowercase letters as input or output, but only use either case.

Comment: Trailing whitespace okay?

Comment: @Okx Yes, note my previous comment.

Comment: What about a lot of trailing spaces?

Comment: @Okx Forbidden, one is all you get.

Comment: I assume we can use lowercase letters instead, right?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder If you keep it consistently at _only_ lowercase letters, yes.

Comment: Is it alright to have a single leading space?

Comment: @miles Leading newlines yes, but no leading spaces.

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 81 bytes

```python
t=[]
i=65
for c in input():t+=[' ']*26;t[ord(c)-i]=c;i-=1
print`t`[2::5].rstrip()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8Q2OpYr09bMlCstv0ghWSEzD4gKSks0NK1KtG2j1RXUY7WMzKxLovOLUjSSNXUzY22TrTN1bQ25Cooy80oSShKijaysTGP1iopLijILNDT//1f3cPXx8Q/3D/JxUQcA)

Answer (score 11):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes

```
''jtfy65-+(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X109qySt0sxUV1vj/38PVx8f/3D/IB8XAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8F9dPaskrdLMVFdb479LyH/HKC5HJ2cuR2dXLmcnRy4PVx8f/3D/IB8XAA).

#### Explanation

MATL indexing is 1-based. [This golfing trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133943/36398) is used here. [This other one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/86227/36398) cannot be used because we need an empty string, not an empty numeric array.

Consider input `'ACE'` as an example. Stack contents are shown bottom to top.

```
''     % Push empty string
       %   Stack: ''
j      % Input string
       %   Stack: '', 'ACE'
t      % Duplicate
       %   Stack: '', 'ACE', 'ACE'
f      % Indices of nonzero entries. Gives [1 2 ... n] where n is input length
       %   Stack: '', 'ACE', [1 2 3]
y      % Duplicate from below
       %   Stack: '', 'ACE', [1 2 3], 'ACE'
65     % Push 65
       %   Stack: '', 'ACE', [1 2 3], 'ACE', 65
-      % Subtract, element-wise. Characters are converted to codepoints
       %   Stack: '', 'ACE', [1 2 3], [0 2 4]
+      % Add, element-wise
       %   Stack: '', 'ACE', [1 4 7]
(      % Fill string '' with values 'ACE' at positions [1 4 7]. The original
       % empty string is extended. Non-existing values are filled with char 0,
       % which is displayed as space. Implicitly display
       %   Stack: 'A  C  E'
```

Comment: `(`: nice builtin

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I think it's similar to 05AB1E's `ǝ`? Ah, but that doesn't seem to vectorize over the second/third inputs

Comment: Exactly why it's unique :p and also how MATL auto-fills with `0`s and displays `0` as space.

Comment: @LuisMendo Nice answer.  Out of curiosity, and this question is probably applicable to most stack based langs, when you write in MATL do you need to keep track of the stack (eg, in a line above the code, or a piece of paper, etc) as you compose code?  Or has it become natural enough to you that you don't?

Comment: @Jonah Thanks! In the beginning I used to need to keep track of the stack on paper. Now it has become natural, and I only need it in more complicated programs

Comment: Heh - learned something new today; you can index into the same position twice without any problem in MATL(AB). I already started writing a complicated loop-based answer because I assumed it would give an error otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>140</s> <s>133</s> <s>129</s> 74 bytes

Saved a ton of bytes porting an ASCII value approach like everyone else. Sad I didn't think of it before :(

```r
function(s){F[X-65+1:sum(X|1)]=X=utf8ToInt(s)
F[is.na(F)]=32
intToUtf8(F)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfk5lUlFhUqZGbWpKRn1KsyZWmYKP7P600L7kkMz9Po1iz2i06QtfMVNvQqrg0VyOixlAz1jbCtrQkzSIk3zOvBKiCyy06s1gvL1HDDShlbMSVmVcSkh8KVAAUqP2fpqHuGKUONFdD3dnJUV3zPwA)

#### original answer, 129 bytes:

```r
function(s){o=rep(' ',(n=nchar(s))+25)
for(i in 1:n){k=substr(s,i,i)
o[x<-i+match(k,LETTERS)-1]=k
F=max(F,x)}
cat(o[1:F],sep='')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYqxCoMwFAB3v8It72EcLHQRM9iiU6fWqdYhWsVgTSSJYBG/PQ3djrvT7iNazfUX5t6O6m0wGMIsdsMqOyuUBIO7YrpfgISEgmSyG7n2FqPT2b9KgwiFDJNU4j4xs7bG@kwFFRioestiEc3cdiNM9FZUVXF/YJw0bApKNvMNSrrhEXTcgqqTtGyo6RdGCB5uAJI/Cf4beUlP3lwvOUH3Aw)

generates a too-long list `o` of spaces, then iterates through `s`, replacing the values in `o` with the correct value and updating `F`, the position of the rightmost character. Then prints out the first `F` elements of `o` with no separators between them.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>20</s> 16 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to Emigna

```
ð₄×svyAuykN+ǝ}ðÜ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/8wNWFiMWX//8Ow4oKEw5dzdnlBdXlrTivHnX3DsMOc//9BQ0U)

Comment: I think you can shorten to `ð₄×svyAuykN+ǝ}ðÜ` at least. Also, is there a guarantee that the input string shifted isn't larger than 1000 chars? If not, `g₂+ð×` should work.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 81 bytes

```js
s=>[...s].map((c,i)=>a[i+parseInt(c,36)-10]=c,a=[])&&[...a].map(c=>c||" ").join``
```

Somewhat builds off of [Rick Hitchcock's incomplete answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145265/69583) but ended up rather different.

Places the characters into their respective index of an empty array, then uses array spread (`[...a]`) to turn the missing elements into `undefined`, allowing `map` to replace empty elements with a space.

### Test Cases

```js
let f=
s=>[...s].map((c,i)=>a[i+parseInt(c,36)-10]=c,a=[])&&[...a].map(c=>c||" ").join``

;["AZ", "ABC", "ACE", "CBA", "HELLOWORLD"]
.forEach(t=>console.log(`"${t}"`, "=>", `"${f(t)}"`))
```

Comment: Very nice!  I was about to post an 88-byte solution, but yours is much better.

Answer (score 5):

### Perl 5, 42 bytes

**41 bytes code + 1 for `-p`. The `\x1b`s in the code are literal escape characters.**

Relies on ANSI escape sequences to position the cursor and therefore doesn't work on TIO.

```pl
s/./($-=-65+ord$&)?"\x1b[$-C$&\x1b[--$-D":$&/ge
```

#### Usage

```sh
perl -pe 's/./($-=-65+ord$&)?"\x1b[$-C$&\x1b[--$-D":$&/ge' <<< 'HELLOWORLD'
     E H    DLL   OLO   R  W
```

Comment: Here's one that works on TIO but comes in at one byte more (41 bytes of code + 2 for `-F`): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUClKFolU1tb18xUO78oJdZWJV7Hwc26oCgzr0QlvqZGRSktv8ih6P9/D1cfH/9w/yAfl3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@67oBAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Xcali You should post that so I can upvote it :)

Comment: @Xcali Agree with Lynn too more posts are great. I like language competition too!

Answer (score 5):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>207</s> <s>191</s> <s>189</s> <s>183</s> <s>178</s> <s>174</s> <s>173</s> 170 bytes

```java
s->{char i=0,l,c[]=new char[s.chars().map(j->j+s.lastIndexOf(j)).max().getAsInt()-64];for(;i<s.length();c[i+l-66]=l)l=s.charAt(i++);return"".valueOf(c).replace('',' ');}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/NasMwEIR7zlMIXyxhW/RQclEcSP9owCXQHHowPqiyksiVZSGt04SQZ3edxqWF0uiyYmZ2lq/iW540VpqqfO9UbRsHqOo12oLSdOYc32fKAxv98f6RV60RoBpDb9Xj8L2UumuMb2vpLmV@eka2fdNKIKG59@iZK4MOHjj00ndosgSnzDpG5zlFWgJIt7RSlihFnU@mB7HhDqn0OtaxyIvUyA90knJPT8NjQmtucZVMq8jT/hTMTSl3ixWuyMna9YG1hJmfG8AkGd8UbNU4zNSkT0uzhg0mTOQq0sl4XKSa6PTcPAOsoogwJ6F1JgjolutW9r2CUCet5kLi8CqMQxQSduzYQDsQbhtVorpnxme0vECcoMMIDW@59yBr2rRAbe@DNvgXO@XW6j0Onh6ybPG6eMnuA0LY1/Lx2H0C)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 41 + (`-F`) = 43 bytes

```perl
map$r[$i++-65+ord]=$_,@F;print$_||$"for@r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUClKFolU1tb18xUO78oJdZWJV7Hwc26oCgzr0QlvqZGRSktv8ih6P9/D1cfH/9w/yAfl3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@67oBAA)

Just for @lynn

Answer (score 4):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 127 bytes

```
,[[-<+<+>>]----[----<<->>]<<-[[>]>++++>[-<[-]<+>>]<[-<++++++++>]<[<]>-]>[>]<[-]+[<]>-[[>]<+[<]>-]>.[-]>[>]<[[->>+<<]<]>,]>>[.>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYyxCgJBEEM/aG7uC0IqBYuFAxuLkEIFQQQLwe9fZ5fzFYFMkrl9rs/343t/9b5IiUCQzkJDgCxbKtGMglVSetYwBjvDwUxTM3BMO3aIPVn1j1VvA3DdF5Na6d5Px9a2y3Zuhx8)

#### Explanation

```
,[                    Take input and start main loop
  [-<+<+>>]             Make two copies of input byte
  ----[----<<->>]<<-    Subtract 64 from one of them to get position in alphabet

                        There are two zero cells between the input and the
                        remaining output cells; we wish to move these zeroes
                        to indicate where the letter is to be moved

  [                     A number of times equal to the position in the alphabet:
    [>]                   Go to current position in output string
    >++++>                Create 4 (as part of creating a space if needed)
    [-<[-]<+>>]           Move output byte back two cells; zero the previous 4 if output existed
    <[-<++++++++>]        Otherwise move a space (32) into that position
    <[<]>-                Move back to counter and decrement
  ]
  >[>]<[-]              Delete last moved byte to make room for input byte
  +[<]>-                Initialize slot at 1 so it is always nonzero in this loop
  [[>]<+[<]>-]          Move input byte into slot
  >.[-]                 Output next output byte and clear
  >[>]<                 Move to space vacated in preparation to remove gap
                        (Moves to end instead if input was A; this causes no problems)
  [[->>+<<]<]           Move values two cells right until zero reached
  >,                    Get into position and take another byte of input
]
>>[.>]                Output characters beyond end of input
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 78 bytes

```
x=>{t=[' ']*26*(q=len(x))for i:0..q{t[i+ord(k=x[i])-65]=k}"".join(t).rstrip()}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxCsIwEADQXylZelcxiGAH4ZwUHAIFF4eQTQNnJUnPGwKl3x7fK5I1pxapVbqsSr7v@jAcxwEW@r4TVMSYpePzwdplVc@7LC@YqXoOuB9PgebNGPvJnEDRyk@FC@DWinBSiGDuN@em5/RwV4PY2h8)

69 bytes by porting Lynn's solution: `x=>{t=[]i=65for k:x{t+=[' ']*26t[ord(k)-i]=k;i--}"".join(t).rstrip()}`

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 bytes

```
ØAiÐ€+JṬ€a"⁸Zḟ€0Ṫ€o⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDMfMwxMeNa3R9nq4cw2QTlR61Lgj6uGO@UC2wcOdq4BU/qPGbf////dw9fHxD/cP8nEBAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>90</s> 88 bytes

```hs
d=drop 1
[a]#s|s<"A"=a:d s|0<1=s
b#s=(s++" ")!!0:d b#d s
f(c:t)=['A'..c]#(' ':f t)
f s=s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FckxCoMwFADQPaf4JkMSLKKrmCFaoYNF6FKoSInaUKla8Tt69zRd3vLeBj@vaXJuUMP2XSEhjWkZHphRTZVJB8AjzhKFpGOoBIYhBSqDIPbTMb/Eij7dpWq45lHUt0xw4KmFXRILqNDNZlxAwWzW6xPEuo3LDhFYCQ3VD3qiOi/@FqW3yLX3UlZVfa9v1Zm27gc)

Comment: @Laikoni Oh dang, I misread that. Will fix...

Comment: Well, it's no longer shorter. :/

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 23 bytes

```
;iB ç
Ng £=hX10nY+XnG
U
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O2lCIOcKTmcgoz1oWDEwblkrWG5HClU=&input=IkhFTExPV09STEQi)

First attempt, may be improvable...

Comment: It looks like you should be able to save a byte by assigning the initial string to `V` instead of `U`: https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=CjtpQiDnCqNWPWhYMTBuWStYbkfDVg==&input=IkhFTExPV09STEQi

Answer (score 2):

## J, <s>37</s> 31 bytes

<s>`` [`]`(' '#~(1+>./)@])}(i.@#+65-~a.&i.) ``</s>

```
[`]`(' '#~(1+>./)@])}#\-66-3&u:
```

-6 bytes thanks to FrownyFrog

#### explanation

The entire thing is a hook:

```
[`]`(' '#~(1+>./)@])}  #\-66-3&u:
```

The right side calculates the new indexes for all the letters.

The left side uses the gerund form of Amend `}` first to create a string of the necessary number of spaces: `(' '#~(1+>./)@])` . And then to place each letter of the original string into its appropriate index within the all-space string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxga6VgoADE/6MTYhM01BXUles0DLXt9PQ1HWI1a5VjdM3MdI3VSq3@a3Ip6Smop9laqSvoKNRaKaQVc3GlJmfkK6QpqDs6u6rDOR6uPj7@4f5BPi7q/wE)

Comment: `(i.@#+65-~a.&i.)` ->  
`(i.@#+65-~3&u:)` ->  
`(i.@#-65-3&u:)` ->  
`(#\-66-3&u:)`

Comment: You can drop the parentheses too.

Comment: @FrownyFrog tyvm.  i'd forgotten about both those golf tricks.

Comment: You can save 3 bytes with `(]' '#~1+>./)`

Comment: @miles. Nice.  I need to make dyadic hooks part of my regular toolbox, I noticed you used them in that revision from this morning as well.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 76 bytes

```
SparseArray[Reverse@MapIndexed[#&@@#2+LetterNumber@#-1->#&,#]]<>""/. 0->" "&
```

Takes a list of characters as input. This generates some error messages that are safe to ignore.

I included `Print` and `Character` command in the footer of the TIO link for ease of use. (`Character` command simply converts a string to a list of characters)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcu7CsIwFADQPV9REgiK1teqhogKCtFKOziEDNf2lnZIKbdR9OtjxzMcD6FBD6EtIdb7SSx6oAEPRPCzOX5whL5Bf@0q/GJlhdRabGYGQ0C6v/0LSYt0nSoh58K5neJ8uUhWqeIJl3G6fVDbBV3rYwME5XgGyxi/nI3JnlluTpwxF/8)

Comment: `LetterNumber` is a built-in for finding the position of a letter in the alphabet? Holy crap, that's ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 88 bytes

```hs
foldr(\c->(((['B'..c]>>" ")++[c])#).(' ':))[]
(x:r)#(y:t)|y>' '=y:r#t|1<3=x:r#t
r#t=r++t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc1BC4IwHAXwu5/izzy4YQrRbTRBTehgCHUI0h1kakVqYy5Q8LO3tMPj93iX9yiHV922ZpB1XQErTPNuK4UL4QUY49yJHN8XPAgQIOK6ueDEJj52wKGE5NzCI1XExhPVZJ6CZWYTVbaet/sdG9dmLWHKdbXpymcPDLpSngDLj75olfbgw/@ZQI7CG9oACqP4T5ysxFG4ckzSNLtm5/SAuPmKpi3vg/GElD8)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>117</s> <s>110</s> 84 bytes

Saved 7 bytes thanks to **Ayb4tu**.

Changed return type from `string` to `char[]` to save 26 bytes.

```cs
n=>{int i=0,l=n.Length;var t=new char[l+26];for(;i<l;)t[i+n[i]-65]=n[i++];return t;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU/BaoNAED0nXzF4UjRSCs1ls4HUpu3BktAccpA9LNtVB8wIO5uUIn67VQw5zcybN@/NM7wyrbODaTQzHF1bOX2Bbrlgrz0auLX4A18aKWTvkKpCgXYVRxNlcfpjby/p@5XMZl4nYGrtCrWFEuRActsheUD5lDSS0txS5Wtx0w68JPs7k5v4ea1E2bpQ4KYRkS8wpgLVav2i5NjEsRLO@qsj8KIfxGj8@MVotgwSJrEH2EHwugsSCHbZfiqf@zw/nA/f@ds0HY/ZRwD9JDN6Wm1quGcDBqRZMoJ7tqwlbhubnh16myPZsAw5isbrftkP/w)

Comment: You can save 7 bytes by changing `t[i+((int)n[i]-65)]` to `t[i+n[i]-65]`.

Comment: @Ayb4btu Thanks forgot that `char -> int` conversions are implicit.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 88 bytes

```
f s|q<-zipWith((+).fromEnum)s[0..]=[last$' ':[c|(c,i)<-zip s q,i==p]|p<-[65..maximum q]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcrBCoIwGADge0/xI4JKOrrUIdxBTeggCF2Exg5DE39yczqFCN99QcddP75BmPdrHK3twexzmnxRN7gOYXiMSL9MslSbjAw7EcIpG4VZ/QCCK2v3sI0x@n8wMMdIqea7ThN2ORMixQflJmHm3EqBCih00wFAL6hW8KEHL3t6DuSFK0XpSJFnjtzLqqqb@lHdPPsD)

`q` is the list of the final indices of the letters of the input string (with an offset of `65`). Loop through all indices (starting at `65`) and find all letters for it, prepending a space. Take the last.

Comment: Yet another 88 byte Haskell solution, see [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145280/34531)  and [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145279/34531).

Answer (score 2):

## Kotlin, <s>207 bytes</s> <s>189 bytes</s> <s>187 bytes</s> 177 bytes

```
fun main(){val i=(readLine()+" ".repeat(26)).toCharArray();for(x in(i.size-1) downTo 0){if(i[x]!=' '){i[x+i[x].toInt()-65]=i[x];i[x]=' '}};print(i.joinToString("").trim())}
```

If the leading blank should remain I would just call `trimEnd()` instead of `trim()`.

**Unminified:**

```
fun main() {
    val m = (readLine() + " ".repeat(26)).toCharArray()
    for (x in (m.size - 1) downTo 0) {
        if(m[x] != ' ') {
            m[x + m[x].toInt() - 65] = m[x]
            m[x] = ' '
        }
    }

    print(m.joinToString("").trim())
}
```

---

Maybe Kotlin is not the best language for code golfing but I liked the challenge and I wanted to make myself more familiar with Kotlin's standard library.

Answer (score 2):

## **C# .NET, <s>89 Bytes</s> 87 Bytes**

-2 bytes thanks to [Lan H.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72738/ian-h)

```
f=>{var s=new char[f.Length+26];for(int i=0;i<f.Length;i++)s[f[i]+i-65]=f[i];return s;}
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##VVDBasMwDL33K0ROCWnDGKwX14Uu67ZDRsN26CHkYDwnEbQ2WG7HCPn2LF7WdH0H2XqSnp8laSGNVT0MkAdBBLk1tRXHmWfa3@hBTjiUcDb4CW8CdUjOoq6LEoStKZr6rhMeH9/k1DF5Pmm5GgfmIBthi3IN1UAC7yu@bs/CAnGtvsZilWRK166J75clq4wNUTtAfsdwdSkxjOOIiqrAMsbF8qHk/sqsciergVjX/7fBbkxNzqUgRcDBPzyRLQSPm2AOwSbd@uN1m2W7/e49e/JZnqcvAXS3goNFJWQDfzsBAtSjeHTZQGo0mYNK9hadylCr0H8/pCi6SnWzrv8B)

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Comment: Thanks! I hope it's ok to post multiple answer in the same language

Comment: You can omit the curly brackets in your `for`-loop for -2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## q/kdb+, 37 bytes

**Solution:**

```
@[max[1+m]#" ";m:!:[x#:]+.Q.A?x;:;]x:
```

**Examples:**

```
q)@[max[1+m]#" ";m:!:[x#:]+.Q.A?x;:;]x:"AZ"
"A                         Z"
q)@[max[1+m]#" ";m:!:[x#:]+.Q.A?x;:;]x:"ABC"
"A B C"
q)@[max[1+m]#" ";m:!:[x#:]+.Q.A?x;:;]x:"ACE"
"A  C  E"
q)@[max[1+m]#" ";m:!:[x#:]+.Q.A?x;:;]x:"CBA"
"  A"
q)@[max[1+m]#" ";m:!:[x#:]+.Q.A?x;:;]x:"HELLOWORLD"
"     E H    DLL   OLO   R  W"
```

**Explanation:**

I think this is the same idea as the J solution, calculate the correct indices for the input array and then assign them to an empty string of correct length:

```
@[max[1+m]#" ";m:til[count x]+.Q.A?x;:;]x: / ungolfed solution
                                        x: / save input as x
@[            ;                     ; ;]   / apply[variable;indices;function;parameters]
                                     :     / assignment
                              .Q.A?x       / location of x in uppercase alphabet
                             +             / added to
                     count x               / length of input
                 til[       ]              / range, 0..n
               m:                          / save as m
  max[   ]                                 / maximum of list
      1+m                                  / m + 1
          #" "                             / take " ", creates empty character list
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 91 bytes

```
reduce(explode|[.,keys]|transpose[]|.[1]+=.[0]-65)as[$c,$p]([];.[$p]=$c)|map(.//32)|implode
```

Expanded

```
  reduce(  explode         # convert string to array of ordinals
         | [.,keys]        # [ [v0,v1,...], [0,1,2,...] ]
         | transpose[]     # [ [v0,0], [v1,1], [v2,2]...]
         | .[1]+=.[0]-65   # adjust position of each value
  ) as[$c,$p] (
    []
  ; .[$p]=$c               # store each value at its position
  )
| map(.//32)               # map null values to spaces
| implode                  # convert back to string
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxNC8IgAIb/y9jB0XR9UJfYYVuDDoNBlyD1IJsHy6lNRwX@9ky6vDwPPLz3Z0iqG1FV3cRpWqKauiLq3HZdf@0v3YmoxFsjhQNJxAxTH2Y@LgMH/G2kHrnHKH/wj6XezUxZoy2PEcIbuioRXlN42GfM4nTIU0MBpkeEI5TpkPmJGYCKYrfNvJj@ZyF8tXFCKxsgVIuUUCizuCgze0G9uCg/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
Ｐ ＦＳ«Ｍ⌕αι→ιＭ⌕αι←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@3NKcks6AoM69EQ0lBSdOaKy2/SEHDM6@gtCS4BCicrqGpqVDNxembX5aq4ZaZl6KRqKOQqamjYBWUmZ5RAtTAGQDWnQliYqrySU0DKar9/9/D1cfHP9w/yMflv25ZDgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｐ                   Output a space to force the indent
   Ｓ                Input string
  Ｆ «               Loop over each letter
       α            Uppercase letters predefined variable
      ⌕ ι           Find index of current letter
     Ｍ   →          Move that many characters right
          ι         Implicitly print the current letter
           Ｍ⌕αι←    Move the same number of characters left
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 26 bytes

Anonymous prefix lambda which takes the input string as argument and returns the output string. Assumes `⎕IO` (**I**ndex **O**rigin) `0`, which is default on many systems.

```apl
{⍵@i⊢''↑⍨1+⌈/i←(⎕A⍳⍵)+⍳≢⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/4MLUlNTgKzqR71bHTIfdS1SV3/UNvFR7wpD7Uc9HfqZQCkNoGrHR72bgSo0tUF05yIgs/Y/RK@CumOUOheM6eSMYDu7wtnOTo5wtoerj49/uH@Qj4s6AA)

`{`…`}` anonymous lambda; `⍵` represents the argument

`≢⍵` tally of the argument

`⍳` than many **ɩ**ntegers (0…LengthOfArgument-1)

`(`…`)+` plus:

`⎕A⍳⍵` the indices of the argument in the uppercase **A**lphabet

`i←` strore in `i` (for **i**ndices)

`⌈/` maximum (reduction)

`1+` add one

`''↑⍨` take that many characters from the empty string, padding with spaces as needed

`⊢` yield that (serves to separate `i` from `''`)

`⍵@i` amend that with the argument letters **at** the `i` indices

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
ā,{ZFWē+1ž
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUwMTAxJTJDJTdCWkZXJXUwMTEzKzEldTAxN0U_,inputs=SEVMTE9XT1JMRA__)

Explanation:

```
ā           push an empty array
 ,{         for each char in the input
   ZFW        get its index in the uppercase alphabet
      ē+      add to that the 0-indexed counter
        1ž    at [pop; 1] insert in the array the current character
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>44</s> 38 bytes

<sub>Striked out 44 is still 44 :(</sub>

Bloody Pyth beginner.

Saved 6 bytes thanks to @Mr. Xcoder.

```
K*d+lz26Vlz K=XK-C@zN-65N@zN;.WqeHdPZK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/31srRTunysgsLKdKwds2wlvX2aHKT9fM1A9IWeuFF6Z6pAREef//7@Hq4@Mf7h/k4wIA)

---

**How?**

```
K*d+lz26Vlz K=XK-C@zN-65N@zN;.WqeHdPZK          Full program

K*d+lz26                                        Assign a string consisting of 
                                                  (26 + input.length) whitespaces to K
        Vlz                                     For-loop from 0 to input.length
                -C@zN-65N                       Calculate the index for the current letter
                         @zN                    The current letter
            K=XK                                Insert the current letter into K at
                                                  position i
                            ;                   End statement
                             .WqeHdPZK          While the last character of H is not a 
                                                  whitespace, pop the last character off K
```

Comment: [38 bytes: `K*d+lz26Vlz K=XK-C@zN-65N@zN;.WqeHdPZK`](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=K%2ad%2Blz26Vlz+K%3DXK-C%40zN-65N%40zN%3B.WqeHdPZK&input=HELLO+WORLD&debug=0). `WqeKd K=PK;K` is replaced by `.W` (functional while) and its arguments of course, and `FNrZlz` can be replaced `VrZlz`, but `rZ...` means `U...`, and `U` is generated automatically by `V`. So `FNrZlz` becomes `Vlz`

Answer (score 1):

## Batch, <s>418</s> 331 bytes

Works with uppercase letters only and will take some seconds for longer strings.

Learned new tricks here, the character to ASCII value conversion using `%=exitcodeAscii%`. Also, `if defined` and "array" access using `call`. Also, golfing by almost 100 bytes was good batch code golf training.

Note the trailing space in `set z=set`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set z=set 
%z%a=%1
:a
%z%v=64
:b
%z%/Av+=1
cmd/Cexit %v%
if %=exitcodeAscii% neq %a:~0,1% goto b
%z%/Ao=v+c
%z%a%o%=%a:~0,1%
if %o%. geq %m%. %z%m=%o%
%z%/Ac+=1
%z%a=%a:~1%
if %a%. neq . goto a
for /l %%n in (65,1,%m%)do (
if defined a%%n (call %z%r=%%r%%%%a%%n%%
)else %z%r=!r! )
echo %r%
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 68 bytes

```ruby
->s{r,w="",-66;s.bytes{|b|r[(b+w+=1).times{|a|r[a]||=" "}]=b.chr};r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664ukin3FZJSUfXzMy6WC@psiS1uLomqaYoWiNJu1zb1lBTryQzFySWCBRLjK2psVVSUKqNtU3SS84oqrUuqv1fUFpSrJAWre7h6uPjH@4f5OOiHvsfAA)

Answer (score 1):

## x86-16 machine code, PC DOS, 27 bytes

```
00000000: b403 cd10 d1ee ad98 91ac b402 8ad0 80ea  ................
00000010: 4102 d343 cd10 cd29 e2ef c3              A..C...)...
```

**Listing:**

```
B4 03       MOV  AH, 3          ; get current cursor position row into DH 
CD 10       INT  10H            ; call BIOS 
D1 EE       SHR  SI, 1          ; SI to DOS PSP 
AD          LODSW               ; AL = command line string length 
98          CBW                 ; AH = 0 
91          XCHG AX, CX         ; CX = length 
        OUTPUT: 
AC          LODSB               ; load DS:SI into AL 
B4 02       MOV  AH, 2          ; BIOS set cursor position function 
8A D0       MOV  DL, AL         ; ASCII char to DL 
80 EA 41    SUB  DL, 'A'        ; convert ASCII char to numeric val (A=0, Z=25) 
02 D3       ADD  DL, BL         ; add current position offset 
43          INC  BX             ; increment position offset 
CD 10       INT  10H            ; move cursor to column in DL
CD 29       INT  29H            ; write char in AL to console
E2 EF       LOOP OUTPUT         ; loop until end of input 
C3          RET                 ; exit to DOS
```

Standalone PC DOS executable.  Input from command line and prints the new "faster" version to console.

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>127</s> 123 bytes

```
function b($i){for($q=0;$q<strlen($i);$q++){$n[ord($i[$q])-65]=$i[$q];}while($x++<26){$m.=$n[$x-1]?$n[$x-1]:" ";}return$m;}
```

[Try it online](https://repl.it/Maak/2)

Had to fix a bug that wouldn't output 'A'...

Comment: To who-ever downvoted: You probably mis-clicked the up-button. Please correct, or drop me a line on why the downvote... Tnx

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript, 136 characters

Replace the variable s by the input string

```
for(s='',w=[],o=[],i=0;i<s.length;i++)w.push(s[i].charCodeAt(0)-65+i);w.forEach((a,b)=>o[a]=s[b]),console.log((o+'').replace(/,/g,' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, <s>135</s> 133 bytes

```
String a(char[]a){char b[]=new char[37+a.length],c=0;for(;c<a.length;b[a[c]-65+c]=a[c++]);return"".valueOf(b).replaceAll("\0*$","");}
```

#### Less Golfed

```
String a(char[]a) {
  char b[]=new char[37+a.length],            // Create an array buffer that is the length of 
                                             // the incoming string plus the length of the 
                                             // alphabet so we have room to move characters
                                             // 37 is arbitrary. We need >26
  c=0;                                       // Also initialize our index variable. chars are
                                             // basically just bytes in java
  for(;c<a.length;                           // Loop over the input
    b[a[c]-65+c]=a[c++]);                    // 'A' is ascii 65 so if we subtract that and add
                                             // the current index, we have the resulting index
                                             // for that character.
  return"".valueOf(b).replaceAll("\0*$",""); // Convert char array to a string and remove any
                                             // trailing nulls that we didn't use
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY9Na4NAFEX3@RWPoYuZmgyB0nZhXRgb6EIQmkVDrIvnZJKYTkYZR5sg/nar/doVinfzLgcO3HfEGmd5IfVx@9YJhWUJa2i6lTWZ3gNScUATJ8iaoUAaJ56W7/BJb@4d5ErqvT0kU@HN3V1uqCsefqCbxhiLZHZ364jE66vjJMw10lZGE8JrVJWMdjRl3MhCoZC@UpS8zq@vyJQQ5rYd9CmqVGUCSou2P3WebeGEmaZfC4dp0EzgO2s4gwfDwjVl7i9eXUorTzyvLC96yypNzxwp8TeE2zzon/GNwQtl7D/SIhhjBcsRVrDwR1hPyzCMXqLn8PEPuZ203Qc)

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 32 bytes

```
;ñ⌠i@O:65@-i+⌡M;Mu' *╗Z⌠i╜T╗⌡MX╜
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9/68MZHPQsyHfytzEwddDO1H/Us9LX2LVVX0Ho0dXoUSOrR1DkhQDZIIgLI/v9fycPVx8c/3D/Ix0UJAA)

#### Explanation

As is customary with my long Actually answers, I'm going to break down the code into sections for the explanation.

**Space Padding**

Input: `s` (a string of uppercase ASCII letters)

Output: a list `L` of new indexes for the letters in `s` on top of the stack, `s` below it on the stack, and a string of spaces of sufficient length to hold the output string in register 0

```
;ñ⌠i@O:65@-i+⌡M;Mu' *╗
                        (implicit input)
;ñ                      make a copy of s, enumerate
  ⌠i@O:65@-i+⌡M         for each [index, character] pair: calculate the new position
   i@O                    ordinal of character (in a list)
      :65@-               subtract 65
           i+             add index
               ;M       maximum index
                 u' *   add one, string of that length containing spaces
                     ╗  save to register 0
```

**Letter Rearranging**

Input: the output from the previous step

Output: the expected challenge output

```
Z⌠i╜T╗⌡MX╜
Z           zip the new indices with their respective letters
 ⌠i╜T╗⌡M    for each [index, character] pair: put the character in that index
  i           flatten pair
   ╜T╗        bring string from register 0, set string[index] to character, save in register 0
        X   discard the empty list from the map
         ╜  push the string in register 0
            (implicit output)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 140 bytes

```
BEGIN{OFS=FS=""}func f(A){for(z=0;sprintf("%c",++z)!=A;);return z-65}{for(;++i<=NF;m=n>m?n:m)a[n=i+f($i)]=$i
for(;++k<=m;)$k=a[k]?a[k]:" "}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd06/a3y3YFoiUlGrTSvOSFdI0HDWr0/KLNKpsDayLC4oy80rSNJRUk5V0tLWrNBVtHa01rYtSS0qL8hSqdM1Ma8FqrbW1M21s/dysc23z7HLt86xyNROj82wztdM0VDI1Y21VMq2hyrJtbHOtNVWybROjs2PtQYSVkoJSreH//x6uPj7@4f5BPi4A)

Designed for uppercase letters, since I'm subtracting 65.
Converting characters to numbers isn't so easy in `AWK`.  This is a few bytes shorter than indexing into a string.

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 126 bytes

```lua
s=""a={}i=-65(...):gsub(".",function(c)a[c:byte()+i]=c i=i+1 end)for j=0,i+91 do s=s..(a[j]or" ")end print((s:gsub(" +$","")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcyxCsIwEADQXzkOhxypwQ4KFm5TcCgUXBxKhzRt5YokkrSDiN8eHdwf77HanBMjWn5/hLeHvTLGUHVPa6/QYDGt3i0SvHJkW1f1r2VUpKVjB8KiSxj9QFOIMPOuEH0sYQiQOBmjbDt3ISIg/Qw8o/hFqfSvQW@wQCSinPPlXNfNrbnWpy8)

Answer (score 0):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 122 bytes

```lua
s=explode&read()t={}n=0s.map(load'a,b=...k=b+byte(a)-byte"A"t[k]=a n=max&n|k')for i=1,n do t[i]=t[i]or" "end print(join&t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcUxCsMgFADQq4iDUZpKe4A/FBroEAh06RAyfNGC1XyDcUhpe3ZLlvcwm@hqXcFtS0zWiezQSlXg8yM4rXrGRcaEtsHWgNY6gDmYd3ES1XGfX3gZwwTICGbcBH1Do54pMw/nlphNrIx@gp2UOeOOLFuypyJfyZMoqtZb1/fDY7j31z8)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP 7.1, 54+1 bytes

Insert a space between the quotation marks for older PHP.

```php
for($r="";$c=$argn[$i++];)$r[$i+ord($c)-66]=$c;echo$r;
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9a9a6a3ef48b3da64e698408fc833e2653e4a857).

Answer (score 0):

## Japt `-h`, 14 bytes

```
;åÈhYZ+BbY}Ucç
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O+XIaFlaK0JiWX1VY+c=&input=IkhFTExPV09STEQiCi1o)